# get input stream of zipped file?

Tags: java

Is it possible to get a file as InputStream from the zipped file? I only know this one here: [How to extract a single file from a remote archive file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125841/how-to-extract-a-single-file-from-a-remote-archive-file) which gives me just the bytes of the file.

so is there any functionality to have a method like this: `InputStream getFile(String path, File zipFile)` where the `path` is the path inside the ziped File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(file);
try {
  InputStream in = zf.getInputStream(zf.getEntry("file.txt"));
  // ... read from 'in' as normal
} finally {
  zf.close();
}
```

For more info refer [this tutorial](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/compression/zip.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) which takes a byte array as an input in the constructor.