# How to extract single file from remote zip archive on non-anonymous FTP using PHP?

Tags: php, ftp, zip

I'm trying to find a solution implemented in PHP to extract a single file from a zip archive stored on a non-anonymous FTP.

The Problem is: I can't use a FTP URL like "ftp://user:pass@www.domain.com/archive.zip" to create a valid ZipArchive-object, which could handle the remaining tasks. (I tested this with a local archive.)

I also tried using the Phar extension and the File_Archive package - to no avail.

[Java seems to offer a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125841/how-to-extract-a-single-file-from-a-remote-archive-file), but the server in question only runs PHP.

Does anyone of you have another approach in mind to solve the problem?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: "I can't use a FTP URL...to create a valid ZipArchive-object," Why not? Please say what error you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you unable to download the zip to a local file and then unzip it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can install the Pecl library [zip](http://pecl.php.net/package/zip) then you should be able to use the functions [zip_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php) and [zip_entry_read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-read.php) to do what you want.