# Read xml file and its contents during apk installation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source, android-sdk-tools, android-package-managers

I am working with some framework code of Android AOSP. I want to read a xml file during installation (at the beginning) of apk/ app-bundle. As I need to read the file before successful installation, I am limited to read it from asset folder using straight forward approach.

I could read the file just after the successfully installation of the apk before showing the success message. As the package is already installed, I can read the file without any trouble.

However, I want to read the file before starting installation, just during parsing of the package. It is okay to read the file just before reading the AndroidManifest.xml file.

The problems I encountered so far -

(1) I tried to read the file along with AndroidManifest.xml file. Problem is, if I keep the my desired xml file in the same path as of AndroidManifest.xml file, the system doesn't include this xml while preparing apk file. As such, it is not possible to read the file along with Manifest file as the resource is absent here.

(2) If I keep the file in Asset folder, before successful installation of the package, it is not possible to access the absolute path of the xml file. This is because, I can not create/ access the context of desired package before installation of the package. Like, following code doesn't work due to unknown package name

Context appContext = this.createPackageContext(packageName, 0);

Is there anyway to read the file during parsing of the whole package and access the contents of the xml file?

Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Comment: The APK file is just a zip. Try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/32179094/192373

Comment: the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38022259/192373 works for API 26 and higher

Comment: My intention is to modify in framework so that during installation it can extract resources from APK/ app-bundle. For example, APKs usually parsed in PackageParser.java for installing it into the system. I want to add my customized method to reread some other files before installation.

Comment: have you tried the FileSystem solution?

Comment: No I didn't. I think I need to remove the directory and apks after reading the xml. However, I will still check and update here.