# Read single file from remote Iso Image within Java

Tags: java, http, extract, iso

I have a complicated requirement. We have a big .iso file being present on a remote server. The file contains a small .txt file which is containing important information about the iso (version).
I need to check this file before(!) downloading the complete iso file. This needs to be done within Java.

For ZIP files I found a solution here ([How to extract a single file from a remote archive file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125841/how-to-extract-a-single-file-from-a-remote-archive-file)), but I am not pretty sure, if this is also not downloading the whole file.

I had a look for the loopy (http://loopy.sourceforge.net/) library, but seems that they only work with "File" objects, which needs the file to be on local drive.

ISO is 9660 format.

What would also be possible is reading the "Lable" of the ISO within Java, because it also contains that version information.

Does anybody has a suggestion? :)

Thanks in advice