# Extract or read single file from remote TGZ archive using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, networking, extract, remote-access, tarfile

i'm trying to download a single text file from a remote TGZ archive using Python 3, but at the moment i only can doing it downloading the whole TGZ in memory and then using tarfile as a local file, the problem is than i can't use the mode `r:gz` when using a remote file and that don't let me extract a single file because random access is not allowed (using `r|gz` dont let me open the remote archive); my working code is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

''' This script reads a configuration TOML file from a TGZ remote compressed archive '''
# import urllib.request
import tarfile
import sys
import argparse
# from lzma import LZMAFile
import requests
import io


def main(args):
    ''' gets the TOML data from the TAR archive '''

    # tgz_file_url example: http://localhost/npm/creard-npm/@creard/helloworldmodule/-/helloworldmodule-1.0.0.tgz
    tar_stream = requests.get(args.tgz_file_url)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(fileobj=io.BytesIO(tar_stream.content), mode="r:gz")
    # toml_path example: package/assets/config/data/module_setup.toml
    tar_member = tar_file.getmember(args.toml_path)
    data = tar_file.extractfile(tar_member).read()
    sys.stdout.write(str(data))


def arguments():
    ''' gets arguments '''

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Script for that reads a configuration TOML \
         file from a TGZ remote compressed archive"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--toml_path", help="The TOML file path inside the TGZ archive", 
        type=str,
        required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        "--tgz_file_url", help="The URL of the remote TGZ archive",
        type=str,
        default=sys.stdin.read())

    return parser.parse_args()

ARGS = arguments()
main(ARGS)
```

I see is posible in java like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125841/how-to-extract-a-single-file-from-a-remote-archive-file) but i don't want to depend in Java

Comment: Do what the Java code does, but in Python instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeah i though that but i do not know how, in java it is used ZipInputStream but do not know if there is a TarInputStream for python or something similar, i just did not find it, only found what is in the script i posted here, thanks